# Use of unresolved identifier 'GraphRequestHTTPMethod'

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to fetch the user details after integrating the FBSDK.But unfortunately I am getting an error like "Use of unresolved identifier 'GraphRequestHTTPMethod'".If anyone helps me ,Would be great. Thankyou!

```
func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
    let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    loginManager.logOut()
}
func getUserInfoFromFB() {

    let params = ["fields":"cover,picture.type(large),id,name,first_name,last_name,gender,birthday,email,location,hometown"]

    let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: params)
    graphRequest!.start {(urlResponse, requestResult) in
        switch requestResult {
        case .failed(let error):
            print("error in graph request:", error)
            break
        case .success(let graphResponse):

            if let responseDictionary = graphResponse.dictionaryValue {
                print(responseDictionary) // Respose is here.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **GraphRequest** Instead of **FBSDKGraphRequest** Here is Working code **(Swift 4)**

```
import FacebookCore
import FacebookLogin

func getUserInfoFromFB() {

    let params = ["fields":"cover,picture.type(large),id,name,first_name,last_name,gender,birthday,email,location,hometown"]
    let graphRequest = GraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: params)
    graphRequest.start {
        (urlResponse, requestResult) in

        switch requestResult {
        case .failed(let error):
            print("error in graph request:", error)
            break
        case .success(let graphResponse):

            if let responseDictionary = graphResponse.dictionaryValue {
                print(responseDictionary) // Respose is here.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output :**

> ["email": abc@gmail.com, "id": 1118625048361749, "name":
>   Nikunj Kumbhani, "picture": {
>       data =     {
>           height = 200;
>           "is_silhouette" = 0;
>           url = "https://platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=1118695008301542&height=200&width=200&ext=1557315519&hash=AeRP_G5QJ0Tlff-8";
>           width = 200;
>       }; }, "last_name": Kumbhani, "first_name": Nikunj]

Comment: getting this error"Cannot convert value of type '(_, _) -> ()' to expected argument type 'FBSDKGraphRequestHandler?' (aka 'Optional<(Optional<FBSDKGraphRequestConnection>, Optional<Any>, Optional<Error>) -> ()>')"

Comment: @Navya This is function return type error by this code you getting success or failed?

Comment: @Navya Just simply call this function by on button click instead of your current code because it's working fine in my current swift 4 project.

Comment: @Navya I already say in my answer you need to use **GraphRequest** instead of **FBSDKGraphRequest** and in this code from where you call this function ?

Comment: if I use graph request I am getting an update error like"Use of unresolved identifier 'GraphRequest'; did you mean 'FBSDKGraphRequest'?Replace 'GraphRequest' with 'FBSDKGraphRequest'"

Comment: by podfile only

Comment: @Navya Cane you please share me which coca pod you Use?

Comment: pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'

Comment: @Navya So you need to Replace 'FBSDKGraphRequest' with 'GraphRequest' and make sure import FacebookCore and 
import FacebookLogin both

Comment: I have already replaced it, then only I am getting that "Use of unresolved identifier 'GraphRequest'; did you mean 'FBSDKGraphRequest'?Replace 'GraphRequest' with 'FBSDKGraphRequest"

Comment: @Navya Are you import this both in this function call class?

Comment: both in the sence??

Comment: @Navya So no chance to get "Use of unresolved identifier 'GraphRequest' this error. because you can see here is a completely working code with the response from my current project.

Comment: So surprisingly it will use the existing access token even if you don't specify it?